# Performing operation on a Sublist that passes a certain test

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function that, when giving two numbers and a list that they belong to, would calculate everything between those numbers (in value).

For example:

averageBetween 4 8 [1,2,8,2,7,2,4,6] = average [4,6,7,8] = 6,25

What I've managed to do so far is:

```
average::[Int]->Double
average [] = 0
average xs = (fromIntegral (sum xs)) / (fromIntegral (length xs)
averageBetween::Int->Int->[Int]->Double
averageBetween a b xs
```

And now I'm kinda stuck, I can't really figure out a way to "filter" my list. Any help would be appreciated.
~

Comment: Why don't you indeed use `filter` as a preprocessing step? As in `averageBetween list = postProcess $ filter (\x -> somePredicateOn x) list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that, aside from a missing closing parenthesis, your `average` function works as expected and can be used in your `averageBetween` function. To find the average of values between a given `a` and `b` in a list, we'll need to filter the list, as you said, eliminating values greater than `max a b` and less than `min a b`. This is important in case we are given our arguments in reverse. Our predicate would thus look something like this:

```
(\x -> (x >= (min a b)) && (x <= (max a b)))
```

We can then call our `average` function on the filtered list, yielding our final function definitions:

```
average :: [Int] -> Double
average [] = 0
average xs = (fromIntegral (sum xs)) / (fromIntegral (length xs))

averageBetween :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Double
averageBetween a b xs = average $ filter (\x -> (x >= (min a b)) && (x <= (max a b))) xs
```

Which can be used just like you'd expect:

```
ghci>> averageBetween 4 8 [1,2,8,2,7,2,4,6]
6.25
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I consulted the haskell documentation but I guess the "filter" function went over my head. I will take note of this in the future.

Comment: @Rad Perhaps you already know about it, but another option in such cases is [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), which searches not only by name but also by type signature (try `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`). The Hoogle instance at haskell.org defaults to only searching within "standard" libraries. If you need a broader range of packages, you can try [Stackage's Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts).

Comment: Note that it's easier to read (and probably just as efficient) to compose two calls to `filter`. `averageBetween a b = average . filter (>= (min a b)) . filter (<= (max a b))`.